# Maven ejb client source - is there a consistent/easy way?

Tags: gwt, ejb, maven

I'm using the maven-ejb-plugin to generate an ejb-client version of an ejb project.  I have a separate entity/domain project where I make a -sources version for use with GWT.

I'm currently running into issues as to where to put persistence.xml for various unit test frameworks (some want it in the entity/domain, others ejb, some both but that causes conflicts with others).  I wouldn't be opposed to merging those two together IF there is an easy way to do ejb-client-sources type of approach for GWT integration.

I do not want a -sources of the full ejb project, and preferably avoid a lot of custom inclusion/exclusions.

Comment: What is a ejb-client-sources for GWT? The sources of an ejb-client that will get compiled in a "special" way?

Comment: That is the intent, yes.  In order for GWT to do it's compiliation of java->javascript, it needs the source code for what it will be using (i.e. the entity/domain code).  Merging both the entity/domain code and the ejb code would reduce the number of modules to maintain, but only if the 'ejb-client' sources problem can be resolved.